# SQL query for finding the media of a set of data belonging to a category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with binned data for different categories, for instance:

```
category, bin, frequency
a, 0, 10
a, 1, 20
a, 2, 30
a, 3, 15
b, 0, 18
b, 1, 54
b, 2, 33
b, 3, 24
```

I need to find the **approximate** median for each category. To do this, I'd like to compute a cumulative percentage histogram for each category and take the first value above 50%. I know how to do this for one category:

```
SELECT category, bin as approx_median
FROM (
SELECT category, bin, frequency,
    (SELECT SUM(frequency) FROM table sub WHERE sub.bin <= base.bin) 
    / (SELECT SUM(frequency) FROM table) 
    * 100 as running_percent    
FROM table base
WHERE category = a
ORDER BY bin ) p
WHERE p.running_percent >= 50.0
LIMIT 1
```

The question is, how do I do this for all the categories to obtain the result

```
category, approx_median
a, 2
b, 1
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT category, Min(bin) As approx_median
FROM(
    SELECT base.category, 
    base.bin, 
    (SELECT SUM(sub.frequency) AS SummeBin FROM [table] sub WHERE sub.bin <= base.bin and sub.category = base.category)
    / (SELECT SUM(sub.frequency) FROM [table] sub WHERE sub.category = base.category GROUP BY sub.category) * 100 as running_percent 
    FROM [table] base
) p
WHERE running_percent >= 50.0
GROUP BY category
```

You need to group the category and also reference it in the aggregations.
If you use SQL Server 2012 and above you can use Window functions. An example for [ABC-Analysis with Window Function](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/abc-classification-with-sql-server-window-function.html).

Comment: I ran it on SQL fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83af53/8) withouth the group by in the sub and it worked.  I don't know if it was lucky or not.  But it does seem to me if you are going to have it in one sub you need it in both.

Comment: You are right it is not necessary, because of the context from base.category. But if you run that specific Subselect by its own you should have a group by category, in order to get the sum of each category. So it was relict of the standalone subselect. Thanks for noting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN operator, I don't konw if it work. Just give it a try.

```
SELECT category, bin as approx_median
FROM (
SELECT category, bin, frequency,
    (SELECT SUM(frequency) FROM table sub WHERE sub.bin <= base.bin) 
    / (SELECT SUM(frequency) FROM table) 
    * 100 as running_percent    
FROM table base
WHERE category in (select distinct category from table)
ORDER BY bin ) p
WHERE p.running_percent >= 50.0
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I don't want to do this for all the categories together, but for each of the categories individually.

Answer (score 0):

If the query you posted is doing what you actually want, then just remove the condition `WHERE category = a` and give it a try. Your running_percent calculation is based on bin column anyway. You may order your outer query further by category to make it look nice maybe.

Comment: But I have to do this per category, not using all the data.

Comment: Did you try though? Can you please share the result you are getting and explain why is it not the result you want?

Comment: The whole point is to divide by categories. Computing the running_percent on all categories makes no sense. But thanks.

Comment: What i'm saying is your calculation is not based on category, it is based on bin column. That's why you actually dont need any group by or smth like that

Comment: Sorry, you are not getting the question. Maybe it's unclear.

Comment: Ok then I decided not to touch you original query, hope this one helps!
select main.category, ( <select just bin column from your original query where category = main.category> )
from table main
group by main.category
It is not the most efficient query ever but I believe it will do what you want